# Is it necessary to close a file after calling ReadAllText?

Tags: c#, file

I am doing the following:

```
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
   string base64 = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
   return new ImageContentDTO
   {
      ImageContentGuid = imageContentGuid,
      Base64Data = base64
   };
}
```

This works perfectly fine. What I want to ask is if I need to Close the file or anything similar after I am done reading from it. And if so, how?

Answer (score 23):

No, you don't have to explicitly close the file, `File.ReadAllText` takes care of that for you.

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) contains this information very explicitly:

> This method opens a file, reads each line of the file, and then adds each line as an element of a string. It then closes the file.
>   [...]
>   The file handle is guaranteed to be closed by this method, even if exceptions are raised.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to close anything when using `File.ReadAllText` since the underling stream reader is closed implicitely.

[MSDN: `File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx)

> Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file, and **then closes the
>   file**.

Here's the implementation in .NET 4 (ILSpy):

```
string result;
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path, encoding))
{
    result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
return result;
```

The `using` statement  disposes the `StreamReader` (even on error), that also closes it.

Comment: I have used ReadAllText and its a window service so first time i am passing 200MB file and it works perfectly then again i pass same file then its throwing Outofmemory exception. is it required to dispose some memory after each operation of ReadAllText?

Comment: @CoreDeveloper: depends on if you still hold the reference to the string. What are you doing with it? Maybe you can consume it somehow and then overwrite the variable with the next result of `ReadAllText`.

Comment: i am making string empty every time before new file comes.

Comment: @CoreDeveloper: maybe you can make it a real question, then we can try to help.

Comment: here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36010525/exception-when-large-file-comes-second-time-in-window-service

Answer (score 10):

I know this question has been answered and this is almost a year now but for those who search and read this question, I would like to suggest you close a file when done with it, or at least do an investigation like my answer shows.

I am no programming expert but I have come across this situation recently.

I created a WinForms c# program and used `File.ReadAllText` to copy text to a string. Afterwards I tried to delete the file, directly from the folder not through the program, but I got an error that the file was still open in another program. I then stopped running the program and was able to delete the file.

That's my experience in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. It might be supposed to do something different, but that's what it did for me.

When I used `StreamReader.ReadToEnd` then `StreamReader.Close` on the same file, I had no problem deleting the file while running the program.

Comment: This is actually how it works in real life. I had to use stream reader to avoid this situation.

Comment: Thanks... I am facing this same problem now..... I innocently thought that the ReadAllText would actually close the file, but in some situations, the file remains opened

Answer (score 3):

You have to close *IDisposable* instances only, usually by means of *using*, e.g.:

```
  // StreamReader is IDisposable and should be Closed/Disposed 
  // either explicitly or by using  
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath)) {
    String base64 = sr.ReadToEnd();
    ...
  }
```

since you don't have an IDisposable instance in your code (File.ReadAllText
returns String which is not IDisposable) you have nothing to Close/Dispose

Comment: Ah I see. +1 for mentioning IDisposable in relation to the return type.

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\_App\files\Data" + dat1 + ".txt");
outputFile.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
outputFile.Close();

StreamWriter outputFileex = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\_App\files\DataEx" + dat1 + ".txt");
outputFileex.WriteLine(sbex.ToString());
outputFileex.Close();
```

Here's a working example I just did with a stringbuilder: "sb". If I remove one of those closes' the file gets generated but the file shows up blank with no data. I had to add in a close to get it to work properly.

Comment: The question is about reading from a file. Your post is about writing to a file so this is not related. In your case, the close calls Flush() first, which empties the memory buffer and writes it physically to the file. This is why you get the content in your file.